# How can I insulate a window against the sound caused by high winds?

Tags: insulation, sound-proofing

I'm on the top floor of an exposed block of flats which is currently being battered by high winds on a nightly basis. I have draught excluders fitted but there's still a lot of noise that comes in through the windows.

I'm wondering if something as simple as packing the window with removable polystyrene blocks would serve to reduce the amount of sound being transmitted into the room?

Comment: What type of windows are they?

Comment: I believe it's an awning window. There's a bit of space on the inside cill to place some form of noise blocking substance.

Answer (score 2):

The peanuts won't do anything as there'd still be gigantic air gaps. Do you want to seal the window? if so, you could get the plastic weather shrink-wrap stuff and seal it from the inside.

Answer (score 0):

Heavy curtains in front will help a bit.